# Change name of mobile android device

Tags: ubuntu-one, android, device-name

I have 2x HTC EVO Android devices.  Both devices show up as Pictures-PC36100.  I have to open the folder and then open a picture inside to figure out which phone the folder belongs to.  Is there anyway to rename the folders to differentiate between phones?

It appears the Ubuntuone android app pulls the phone's model number.  Perhaps the option provide a custom device name when setting up the Ubuntuone Android app on a specific device would be helpful.

Comment: Might be helpful: [Mounting a USB disk in a permanent location](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1644/mounting-a-usb-disk-in-a-permanent-location)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu One Files > Menu > Settings > Configure auto-upload > Upload directory.

Since 1.0.4. We had some issues with the update, though. We'll republish soon as 1.0.4.1.