# Same phone, different folders

Tags: directory, smartphone

I'm sharing Ubuntu One with my girlfriend, who has the same smartphone as me.

As a result both the phone's pictures end up in the same folder.

Is there a possibillity to use different folders?

Comment: You change the name of the uploads directory from the app on the phone. This is a duplicate of [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/72647/change-name-of-mobile-android-device) Have a look and see if that solves it for you.

Comment: @TomBrossman - whilst the solution maybe similar, I think the question is possibly different enough to warrant not marking this as a duplicate.  Please can you add an answer with as much detail as possible?

Comment: @fossfreedom good point, it's done.

Answer (score 2):

No problem at all. The answer is to make new destination folders your Ubuntu One directory on the computer, then point the phone app at these new folders on both phones.

- First, add the desired folder(s) inside your `/home/Ubuntu One/` folder on the
  computer, like this:

[image: Ubuntu One destination folders]

- Now, open up the Ubuntu One Files app on the phones. You should see
  the folders you just created on the list, like this:

[image: Android app screenshot]

If you don't see the folders, touch the 'two arrows in a circle' icon on the right of the orange bar above to force a sync.

- Now, press 'Menu' on the phone, and select 'Configure auto-upload'

[image: Android app screenshot 2]

- Next, select 'Upload directory'

[image: Android app screenshot 3]

- On either phone, select the different directories. That's your save
  location now.

Thanks to karni for the instructions posted in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72647/change-name-of-mobile-android-device), it's what I based this on.